# Want to apply for internal position, but current manager does not approve

Tags: management, career-development, manager, careers

My manager forwarded an email to me about some positions that just opened up; the location is perfect, the job description sounds  perfect...

He said underneath them "Contact me first before applying to any of these". I guess when people apply internally, both managers know about it.

So I scheduled a meeting with him, sat down in his office and told him I'd like to gun for a Level 2 position (I'm Level 1).

He said that he didn't think I was ready since the Level 2 requires two years of professional experience... while he's right, I had been an intern for 1 year (full-time for 3 months of that year) and I now have been on as a Level 1 for 7 months and he told me I need an entire year more...

He told me I could try for the Level 1 doing essentially the same thing as the Level 2, but he didn't seem too enthusiastic.

Not sure what to do, he didn't react at all like I expected... if I move to the Level I, I'm not sure that will advance me other than the fact that I will be a true software developer instead of being part of IT... and my location will greatly reduce my drive time.

Should I still apply for the Level 2?

Comment: @SnWhte Your right. I added the question at the end.

Comment: Do the job that you want to be doing in the future.  If you want to become a developer, search out a developer job, and get out of IT.  If you want to do IT but think this developer job will help you get to Level 2, it won't.  The role you'll be performing in the job, and the experience you will gain, is far more important than the title at this stage in your career.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say if you feel confident that you are qualified for the job and there are no company policy requirements preventing it, give it a try.

You may run into a problem if your manager doesn't sign off on it, so you may need to work on convincing him you have what it takes to move to Level 2. And do take his advice seriously. It's important to stay on good terms with him.

Comment: "It's important to stay on good terms with him."  _Especially_ if you don't get the other role.

Comment: Question: do I convince him before or after I apply? Maybe just applying and getting considered for the Level 2 would be enough

Comment: I'd make a good faith effort first. If you feel you have a strong case then to me it's worth having that conversation.

Answer (score 1):

> the Level 2 requires two years of professional experience... while
>   he's right

I think your answer lays here. If your manager is correct in saying two years professional experience, and you don't have that experience for the level 2, then there's not much to discuss.

> He told me I could try for the Level 1 doing essentially the same
>   thing as the Level 2

I'm not sure I'd ever recommend someone take on a role where the responsibility was the same as a higher level position, but you didn't get the same money (assuming level 2 pays more than level 1) regardless of other benefits such as where it's located.

Comment: I'm at 1 year and 10 months considering the internship as professional experience...

Comment: Understood. I'd clarify with HR if *they* consider that as professional experience for the purpose of levels in your organisation.

Comment: Good idea! HR may know something I don't here. I wish I didn't have to wade my way through unspoken codes all the time

Comment: @KolobCanyon internships don't count and trying for a promotion after 7 months total of work experience is not a good idea

Comment: @Neuromancer fair enough. Just wanted to know